# how to set the contextPath of jetty on xsbt-web-plugin?

Tags: jetty, sbt, maven-jetty-plugin, xsbt-web-plugin

I'm on sbt 0.11.1 and xsbt-web-plugin 0.2.10

here goes the build.sbt and plugins.sbt

## build.sbt

```
organization := "org"

name := "demo"

version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.9.1"

seq(webSettings :_*)

configurationXml := 
                    <configuration>
                        <webApp>
                          <contextPath>/foo</contextPath>
                        </webApp>
                    </configuration>

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "7.4.5.v20110725" % "container",
  "javax.servlet" % "servlet-api" % "2.5" % "provided"
)

resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
```

## project/plugins.sbt

```
libraryDependencies <+= sbtVersion(v => "com.github.siasia" %% "xsbt-web-plugin" % (v+"-0.2.10"))
```

It seems the configurationXml doesn't work, after running container:start in sbt console, the contextPath gets the default value "/"

how can I change the contextPath? any tips? thanks in advance!

Comment: I got an answer on scalatra-user group, please refer: http://groups.google.com/group/scalatra-user/browse_thread/thread/cc3883be7d01d61f

Comment: You are allowed to anser your own question. Why not including the answer from the mailinglist here as answer to your problem to document the solution in place?

Comment: I think [you can answer your own question now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz) with just a little reputation.

Comment: To enable `configurationXml`, `customConfiguration` parameter should be set to true, otherwise it is not applied. However, I couldn't manage it to work due to issues with classpath, etc, and not found any samples of working `configurationXml`. It replaces configuration done by xsbt-web-plugin completely, so everything must be configured from scratch: connectors, context handler, classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution from scalatra-user group

Add jetty-plus to dependencies:

```
"org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-plus" % "7.4.5.v20110725" % "container"
```

Add this to build.sbt:

```
env in Compile := Some(file(".") / "jetty-env.xml" asFile)
```

In the same directory as build.sbt, create the jetty-env.xml:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/foo</Set>
</Configure>
```